# Extract footer data of PDF in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am able to get data from pdf pages in a string.
But along with those, footer data is also extracted. I want to remove those from all the pages of pdf. How can I remove that
I used Rectangle2D but coordinates are not giving data

Comment: *coordinates are not giving data* - what does that mean?

Comment: PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("xyz.pdf");
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get( 1 );
Rectangle2D region = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 10, 10);
String regionName = "region";
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.addRegion(regionName, region);
stripper.extractRegions(page);
System.out.println("Region is "+ stripper.getTextForRegion(region"));
Here I am trying to get data as per the coordinates so that footer gets eliminated

Comment: Well, I doubt the page area defined by the `Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 10, 10)` will contain much text. In many documents that area is a small empty square in the lower left region of the page.

Comment: Oh what area should be used to get only main page contents except footer

Comment: That completely depends on the document.

Comment: I tried with various regions , yet I am not getting any text, If you have idea for a normal pdf page , you should share

Comment: try Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 500, 500) and adjust it from there by trial and error. However it will be difficult if your pages all come from different sources. Footers aren't always the same.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment the OP indicated that he used this code:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("xyz.pdf");
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get( 1 );
Rectangle2D region = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 10, 10);
String regionName = "region";
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.addRegion(regionName, region);
stripper.extractRegions(page);
System.out.println("Region is "+ stripper.getTextForRegion("region"));
```

For most documents this code will extract no text because it looks at a small (10x10 pt) region in the upper left region of the second document page. Thus, the values in `new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 10, 10)` have to change.

> I tried with various regions , yet I am not getting any text, If you have idea for a normal pdf page , you should share

There is nothing like a *normal pdf page*. *The goal of PDF is to enable users to exchange and view electronic documents easily and reliably, independent of the environment in which they were created or the environment in which they are viewed or printed.* There is no serious restriction on page dimensions or location of content on pages.

E.g. for [this form](http://www.canadalifeus.com/site2/pdf3/cla_hipaa.pdf)

[image: Canada Life HIPAA form]

you need values like these

```
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
Rectangle2D region = new Rectangle2D.Float(0f, 230f, 612f, 300f);
```

to extract the body "I authorize any health plan ... I have received a copy of this authorization." without headers, footers, or form lines.

If you have many similar pages (e.g. one large document with many pages with a similarly layout), you have to measure but once for many pages to extract.